# I'm trying to find the difference between two times in two textboxes

Tags: c#

```
textboxSart   >   textboxEnd
```

textboxEnd - textboxStart does the trick, but what if the start was 15:00 and the end was 2:00

I thought of this solution

```
24 - textboxStart + textboxEnd
```

I had to subtract 23:59 then add one minute because there is no 24 hours

```
textboxResult.text = (Convert.ToDateTime("23:59") - Convert.ToDateTime(textBoxStart.Text).AddMinutes(-1)).ToString();
```

But I can't add the value in `textboxEnd`

```
Convert.ToDateTime(textBoxStart.Text).AddMinutes(-1).AddHours(textboxEnd.tex)).ToString();   //i tried this, and i did convert to double but it didn't work
```

Comment: You can convert them to [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) and then subtract them.

Comment: thanks that did work

Comment: that's good. You can now post your solution and mark it as answer so anyone can use it :)

Comment: @jalal how can i mark as answer? :P I'm sorry I'm a new programmer btw and new here too

Comment: you need to wait for few days until you can mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            TimeSpan var1 = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text));
            TimeSpan var2 = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text));
            double overtime = (var1.TotalMinutes * var2.TotalMinutes)/60;

            textBox3.Text = overtime +" "+ "$" .ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(textBoxStart.text);
DateTime end = DateTime.Parse(textBoxEnd.text);
```

To know difference in time unit minutes,
    `int hoursDifference = (int)end.Subtract(start).TotalMinutes;`